# How much BPS(Bits per symbol) is enough to call a compression algorithm good, with respect to entropy?

Tags: entropy, compression

Consider a general purpose lossless data compression algorithm, It compresses a randomly generated binary file of 100MB size, with random I mean I wrote a small Script to create a file with random binary, with entropy **E**(measured in BPS(*Bits per symbol*)) to another file, In which each symbol is represented with **X** bits, i.e **BPS =** **X**.

Such that **X - E = 0.4xxxxx.**

Now the Question is Is this a Good, better, Best, Or Worse algorithm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the question is meaningful without more details, such as file size. There are algorithms, such as [LZ77](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78), which can approach the entropy, on the limit to infinity. That means, for a very large file, LZ77 can approach $X-E=0$.

For smaller file sizes it really depends on the probability distribution. For example, if all probabilities are powers of 2, then the [Huffman code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) can also achieve $X-E=0$.

Comment: Sorry for not giving info about the file, The file is A randomly generated binary file and its size is a 100MB

Comment: A good way to check the performance of your algorithm is to compress the original file using gzip and comparing the results. If you are smaller than gzip, your algorithm is good. But you should reduce expectations for randomly generated binaries, as no compressor can handle this kind of data, by definition.

Comment: Got it. But can you answer it in this terms I mean wheather 0.4xxxxx BPS difference is good or not ?

Comment: Only you can answer this, as only you have the file input. As I said before, measure X-E for the gzip output, if your value of 0.4 is less than the gzip X-E, then it's surely good.